# How can I set kerberos principal in environment automatically on the remote host?

Tags: environment-variables, pam, kerberos

I use both legacy `krsh` and ssh to login to a variety of boxes for root administration, as do several colleagues of mine.
We all keep different history files by use of a variable calculated by running grep through /var/log/messages for $PPID, which feels very hacky to me.

I'd like to do it via something like /etc/security/pam_env.conf - but I can't for the life of me find any kerberos principal like variables set via GSSAPI, SSH, PAM or klogind/xinetd.
I hope someone comes across this who has been in the scenario before as it's making me crazy. I've considered patching and rebuilding pam_krb5 rpm, but it seems overkill.

Answer (score 0):

The hard work answer it would appear is to recompile both sshd and krb5-libs. The wonder of open source software.